# Element-wise multiplication between array and matrix

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, multiplication

In R, I can have piece-wise multiplication between a matrix and a (conformal) vector, for example:

```
X <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4), nrow = 2)
a <- c(0, 1)
X * a
```

Each row of the matrix is then multiplied with the corresponding vector element. I can also do the same for arrays of dimension bigger than 2:

```
XX <- array(X, dim = c(2, 2, 2))
a <- c(0, 1)
XX * a
```

Again each row is multiplied with the corresponding vector element. Can I do something similar for an 3d array and a 2d matrix? I just want every submatrix of the array to be element-wise multiplied with a matrix.

Comment: You can slice with `apply`, but it calls `as.vector` on the results of each slice, destroying the dimensions. It's doing all the calculations, though, so you could reset dimensions (very carefully!) if you like. Another workaround is to chuck each slice in a list to stop it from getting simplified.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot multiply it with 2d matrix, but you could try this 
`XX*c(1,2,3,4)`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to achieve 'piece'-wise multiplication (or any arithmetic operation, really) by first constructing an appropriate array from the lesser-dimensional matrix and then performing the element-wise operation. In your example:

```
X <- 1:8
XX <- array(X, dim = c(2, 2, 2))
a <- c(0, 1)

# construct array for point-wise operation
expandeda <- array(a, dim=dim(XX))

XX * expandeda
```

The result of this shows that, as you said, the individual elements of `a` are applied row-wise (i.e. to the first dimension of the array):

```
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    2    4

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    6    8
```

Constructing an appropriate array using `array(a, dim=dim(XX))` doesn't just work for 3d and 2d matrices but for *any* dimensionality of arrays, as long as `length(a) == dim(XX)[1]`.